# ios7 After adding refresh control to table view as subview it adds extra space

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uirefreshcontrol

I have added UiRefreshController to UiTableView as subview and it works well but it also adds extra space to the head of the table view. This problem only appear in iOS7.

code:

```
refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refreshControl.tag = 99;
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
self.tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
[refreshControl beginRefreshing];
[refreshControl endRefreshing];
```

[image: without uirefresh controller][image: after adding uirefresh controller]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this to the view controller:

```
viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

iOS7 may be adding some extra space trying to fill the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem couple days ago.

By adding 
`viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`

will eliminate the extra space after pulling to refresh, however, if you look carefully, you will find the navigation bar color are modified too after adding the previous code line.

However, adding pull to refresh function using storyboard will give you the clean output.

Select TableViewController on your storyboard -> under attribute inspector -> set "Refreshing" to Enabled.